# How do I properly handle file copy/cut & paste in javafx?

Tags: java, file, javafx, clipboard, copy-paste

I'm working on a program in which I want to add the possibility of copy-pasting (or cut-pasting) files. I could create it so it only works within the program, but it would be nicer if I could use the system-wide clipboard. That has one huge problem though: when pasting I don't know if files are copied or cut from the system explorer, I only get the file locations.

I am using Java and the javafx clipboard. Some sample code:

```
Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
List<File> files = clipboard.getFiles();

// destDir is a File, the target directory.
for (File oldFile : files) {
    if (oldFile.isDirectory()) {
        FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory(oldFile, destDir);
    } else {
        FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(oldFile, destDir);
    }
}
```

Here I simply copy the files, but how do I for example know when to use `FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory` and when to use `FileUtils.moveDirectoryToDirectory` (aka copy or cut)?

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: You can't. Clipboard will only give you paths or - in general - data. You could add Buttons to your Dialog for "Cut" or "Copy". You may also be interested in [Drag&Drop](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm)

Comment: Not sure if `DragBoard` yields a valid value for the TransferMode when using ctrl+c/ctrl+v etc.

Comment: @Fildor The system clipboard unfortunately does not have a TransferMode... Drag and drop may indeed be a better option for moving files from the program to the explorer and vice versa. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, [as pointed out by Fildor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133307/how-do-i-properly-handle-file-copy-cut-paste-in-javafx#comment56014835_34133307) , that this is only possible when using drag and drop with the Dragboard. The Clipboard does not have such functionality.